# OpenCV(4.1.0) error: (-215:Assertion failed)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am following this tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4K6D_gx2Iw&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfhTox0AjmQ6tvTgMBZBEXN&index=6

When I try to use the model outside the program by prediction it gives me the following error:
error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3718: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Below the code when loading the model:

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]
    import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 50
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    #return img_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
#
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('iyad')
#
predication = model.predict([prepare("Dog.jpg")])

print(predication)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using macOS

Comment: The image is not loaded. Check if you have `Dog.jpg` in the folder. Also, please note `Dog.jpeg` differs `Dog.jpg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tells you the size of the original image is 0, corresponding to when you read from `img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`. Check if you do have that picture `Dog.jpg` loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In addition @stormzhou answer:
Just type this your script or ipython cell to verify if there is an empty or corrupt image that might create this error .

```
import os
from PIL import Image

img_dir = r"/content/downloads/Cars"
for filename in os.listdir(img_dir):
    try :
        with Image.open(img_dir + "/" + filename) as im:
             print('ok')
    except :
        print(img_dir + "/" + filename)
        os.remove(img_dir + "/" + filename)
```

Replace img_dir to the directory name from where you are trying to resize the images. Hope it was helpful .

Answer (score 0):

**It's a path error. Put the correct and full path.**

Problem 1: When you run it from an IDE, the IDE console's path might be different and might not be able to locate the image so provide the full path i.e. instead of image.png do something like:
`_image = cv2.imread(r'C:/Desktop/pc_name/Desktop/images/cat.png')`

Problem 2: Image extension. Check if the image is `.jpg` or '.png' or other.

Problem 3: You've written an incorrect image name or the image simply doesn't exist at the location provided.

Comment: i load images using glob.glob and still get this error, but only when using a trackbar

Answer (score 0):

```
    X=[]
count=0

path=TRAIN_PATH_X
for img in os.listdir(TRAIN_PATH_X):
    image=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    try:
        image = cv2.resize(image, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        print(image.shape)
    except:
        break
    X.append([image])
    count = count +1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

error 215 assertion failed usually occurs when the image is not loading correctly, so check the path of the image

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).